# How to copy a DLL file to tasks folder in VBA for MS Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I can copy a DLL file to a certain tasks folder in Windows (C:\Windows\System32\Tasks) using the /Y flag in windows command line but when I try to do the same in VBA in word it keeps failing for some reason.

This is the command working in windows command line:

```
copy /Y tasks.dll C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\tasks.dll
```

And this is what I have so far in VBA?

```
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim dFile As String

    ' This is Your File Name which you want to Copy
    sFile = "C:\public\test.dll"

    ' Change to match the destination folder path
    dFile = "C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\test.dll"

    ' Copy file to destination folder
    Shell "cmd.exe /k copy /Y " & sFile & dFile
```

I expect it work for some reason beyond my skill it doesn't. Any help in solving this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without running and checking any code (I don't want to run shell commands today!), your problem will be in this line:

```
Shell "cmd.exe /k copy /Y " & sFile & dFile
```

If you checked through (step by step) and watched the variables, you will see that this equates/expands to:

```
Shell "cmd.exe /k copy /Y C:\public\test.dllC:\Windows\System32\Tasks\test.dll"
```

Looking at this, you can see that you are missing a space between the file names, so the "cmd.exe" command can't resolve the arguments.

Simple fix, insert the space!:

```
Shell "cmd.exe /k copy /Y " & sFile & " " & dFile '<-- include the space
```

Comment: So this works for copying to other folders but for some reason it can't copy to the tasks folder unless done in cmd window with copy and the /Y flag.

Comment: Perhaps, but my answer above addresses your immediate question about why it was not working through VBA. Feel free to mark as answered if you does indeed address that immediate question.